# How to return cell address if you know cell value

Tags: c#, excel

Heads up that I am very new to coding.

I'm writing code in c# and I've linked to an excel document.

I need to be able to find the cell address of a cell that has a cell value that I already know. For example, I need to find the address of the cell that has the word 'chocolate' and for it, for example, to return "A2".

Here's what I've written so far but I'm very new to coding so don't know if it works:

```
using System;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Name
{
   class Program
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
   class Excel
   // client can put in their own excel spreadsheet and whatever worksheet within it, they then put the time down 
   static int GetCellValue(string ExcelSheet = "C:\Users\Laura Dennis\Desktop\Translation 
Internship\Coding\Data.xlsx", int worksheet = 2, int time)
        {
            // create app
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            // open workbook
            var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(
                @ ExcelSheet
            );
            // open worksheet
            var Excel.Worksheet worksheet = worksheet;
            // get the value for each cell
            int value = cell.InnerText
            // read each cell within the first column
            Excel.Range namedRange = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("A2", "A55");
            // see if it matches
            foreach (Excel.Range cell in namedRange.Cells)
            {
                // return cell address and from here can get other cell values to calculate the 
outstanding series of payments
                if (value == time)
                    {string RangeAddress(Excel.Range rng)
                        {
                            return rng.get_AddressLocal(false, false, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, 
missing, missing);
                        }
                    }
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please be more specific what error you are getting. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then try to improve your question by editing it, focusing on a specific problem and giving details about it (code, configuration, error messages, exact problem your are facing.

Comment: Clean up the readability of your code when you post. (One doesn't need the usings etc to review) This line does not compile in your example `if (value == time)
                    {string RangeAddress(Excel.Range rng)` please resolve.

Comment: You appear to have the process down, but its unclear what your issue is....exactly what is causing you to not complete the code? For searching the range looks ok, so what *exactly* is stopping you?

Comment: For searching you could use [Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find?view=excel-pia). This method returns a Range object which has Address property.